# @Retryable is not working on Spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Tags: java, spring-retry, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add retry logic in my (spring boot gradle plugin) application by adding `@Retryable`.

What i have done so far:

Added latest starter aop in class path:

```
classpath(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-aop', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE')
```

Retry class:

```
@Component
@EnableRetry
public class TestRetry {
    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000))
    public void retryMethod() {
        throw new RunTimeException("retry exception");
    }
}
```

Test logic:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class CallRetryClass {
    public void callRetryMethod() {
        TestRetry testRetry = new TestRetry();
        testRetry.retryMethod();
    }
}
```

But the retry logic is not working. Do anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use spring-managed bean of `TestRetry` instead of constructing your own object. `CallRetryClass` should look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class CallRetryClass {

    @Autowired
    private TestRetry testRetry;

    public void callRetryMethod() {
        testRetry.retryMethod();
    }
}
```